# how to track goal points?

Tags: php, function

I am having a goal for the user that needs to hit and that user passed the goal I want it to show a different color. So right now I have total goals needed by having goals_needed * time_spent / day_length.

For example if the goal is 10, and user gets 11 points I want it to show a different color because he passed the goal. How would I get the result to show passed goal ?

I was thinking something like this

```
$color_performace = function($value, $goal) {
    if($value < $goal)
        return 'notenough';
    elseif($value >$goal)
        return 'awesome';
    else
        return 'enough';
};
```

and function

```
$total_goals_class = $color_performance($total_goals,round($goals_needed*$goal_multiplier));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you are after but if you want to deal with getting things on the page to change colour you will need to output html & css.

So perhaps have something like:

```
$color_performace = function($value, $goal) {
    if($value < $goal)
        return '<p style="color: red;">notenough</p>';
    elseif($value >$goal)
        return '<p style="color: green;">awesome</p>';
    else
        return '<p style="color: yellow;">enough</p>';
};
```

That is a quick and dirty example to show the concept, I would probably change it to use classes and have the css set in a main file somewhere, and use hex codes for colours.